# MATLAB MEX file on Linux fails to find symbols in libpython.2.7.so

Tags: python, linux, matlab, shared-libraries, mex

I've been working on a [project](https://github.com/cgranade/pymex-embed) to embed the Python interpreter into MATLAB as a MEX-file, using libpython2.7.so, but encounter a problem whenever I try to import Python modules implemented as extension modules. For example, attempting to import `itertools` results in the following error:

```
>> py_import itertools
ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertoolsmodule.so: undefined symbol: PyTuple_Type
??? Error using ==> pymex_fns
Python exception inside py_import.

Error in ==> py_import at 24
    py_obj = pymex_fns(py_function_t.IMPORT, name);
```

This behavior occurs whether or not I clear `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before the call to `Py_Initialize()`, and a call to `ldd` (for `itertools.so`, in this example) from within MATLAB doesn't result in any `(not found)` messages. Below, I've pasted the results of running MATLAB with `LD_DEBUG=libs` set, first with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set by MATLAB's startup, and then after running `setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', '')` before attempting to import.

How can I fix this problem, and allow for the dynamic loading of extension modules?

With MATLAB-default `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
>> py_import itertools           
      3018: find library=libpython2.7.so.1.0 [0]; searching
      3018:  search path=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/../../bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64      (RPATH from file /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB)
      3018:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/../../bin/glnxa64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      3018:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      3018:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      3018:  search path=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/os/glnxa64        (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
      3018:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/os/glnxa64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      3018:  search path=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64       (RPATH from file /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB)
      3018:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      3018:  search path=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/extern/lib/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64     (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
      3018:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/extern/lib/glnxa64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      3018:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/runtime/glnxa64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      3018:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      3018:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      3018:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      3018:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      3018:   trying file=/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      3018: 
      3018: find library=libutil.so.1 [0]; searching
      3018:  search path=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/../../bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64      (RPATH from file /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB)
      3018:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/../../bin/glnxa64/libutil.so.1
      3018:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/libutil.so.1
      3018:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libutil.so.1
      3018:  search path=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/os/glnxa64        (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
      3018:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/os/glnxa64/libutil.so.1
      3018:  search path=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64       (RPATH from file /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB)
      3018:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/libutil.so.1
      3018:  search path=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/extern/lib/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64     (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
      3018:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/extern/lib/glnxa64/libutil.so.1
      3018:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/runtime/glnxa64/libutil.so.1
      3018:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads/libutil.so.1
      3018:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libutil.so.1
      3018:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/libutil.so.1
      3018:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      3018:   trying file=/lib64/libutil.so.1
      3018: 
      3018: 
      3018: calling init: /lib64/libutil.so.1
      3018: 
      3018: 
      3018: calling init: /lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      3018: 
      3018: 
      3018: calling init: /home/cgranade/academics/software-projects/pymex-embed/src/pymex_fns.mexa64
      3018: 
      3018: /home/cgranade/academics/software-projects/pymex-embed/src/pymex_fns.mexa64: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: mexLibrary (fatal)
      3018: /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertoolsmodule.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: PyTuple_Type (fatal)
??? Error using ==> pymex_fns
Python exception inside py_import.

Error in ==> py_import at 24
    py_obj = pymex_fns(py_function_t.IMPORT, name);
```

With `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` cleared:

```
>> py_import itertools           
      3125: find library=libpython2.7.so.1.0 [0]; searching
      3125:  search path=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/../../bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64      (RPATH from file /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB)
      3125:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/../../bin/glnxa64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      3125:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      3125:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      3125:  search path=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/os/glnxa64        (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
      3125:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/os/glnxa64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      3125:  search path=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64       (RPATH from file /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB)
      3125:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      3125:  search path=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/extern/lib/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64     (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
      3125:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/extern/lib/glnxa64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      3125:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/runtime/glnxa64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      3125:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      3125:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      3125:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      3125:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      3125:   trying file=/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      3125: 
      3125: find library=libutil.so.1 [0]; searching
      3125:  search path=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/../../bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64      (RPATH from file /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB)
      3125:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/../../bin/glnxa64/libutil.so.1
      3125:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/libutil.so.1
      3125:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libutil.so.1
      3125:  search path=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/os/glnxa64        (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
      3125:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/os/glnxa64/libutil.so.1
      3125:  search path=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64       (RPATH from file /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB)
      3125:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/libutil.so.1
      3125:  search path=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/extern/lib/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64     (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
      3125:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/extern/lib/glnxa64/libutil.so.1
      3125:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/runtime/glnxa64/libutil.so.1
      3125:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads/libutil.so.1
      3125:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libutil.so.1
      3125:   trying file=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/libutil.so.1
      3125:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      3125:   trying file=/lib64/libutil.so.1
      3125: 
      3125: 
      3125: calling init: /lib64/libutil.so.1
      3125: 
      3125: 
      3125: calling init: /lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      3125: 
      3125: 
      3125: calling init: /home/cgranade/academics/software-projects/pymex-embed/src/pymex_fns.mexa64
      3125: 
      3125: /home/cgranade/academics/software-projects/pymex-embed/src/pymex_fns.mexa64: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: mexLibrary (fatal)
      3125: /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertoolsmodule.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: PyTuple_Type (fatal)
```

Comment: interesting project. I haven't looked into the problem above, but I just want to point to other similar projects for embedding Python interpreter into MATLAB: [matpy](http://algoholic.eu/matpy/), [pymex](https://github.com/kw/pymex), [pythoncall](https://github.com/pv/pythoncall), [pymex](http://vader.cse.lehigh.edu/~perkins/pymex.html)

Comment: @Amro: I had somehow missed those when I was looking around, so thanks for the links! I didn't note any that also supported Win64, which is a requirement for me, and the lack of complex matrices in kw/pymex is disappointing, but it might be make sense for me to focus my efforts on forking that project... definitely something to think about, so thanks again for the links!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the regular python both from inside MATLAB and on the system shell:

#### Shell

```
$ LD_DEBUG_OUTPUT=./ld_debug_out LD_DEBUG=all python -c 'import numpy'
```

#### MATLAB

```
>> !LD_DEBUG_OUTPUT=./ld_debug_out LD_DEBUG=all python -c 'import numpy'
```

and inspect the output files (maybe `all` is a bit too much info!). Note I imported `numpy` instead since `itertools` does not have a corresponding shared library on my installation..

---

One idea is to try to manually load the shared libraries in your MEX function before calling `Py_Initialize()`:

```
dlopen('libpython2.7.so', RTLD_GLOBAL|RTLD_LAZY);
```

---

I am on a Windows machine, but last time I played with this I had some problems as well. I remember that once imported, some C extension modules could not be unloaded and reloaded in the same session (during the lifetime of the hosting process where Python is embedded). See these [remarks](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Reloading_Python_Interpreters) and related [PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3121/).

Comment: Adding the dlopen() call fixed almost all of the problems I was having with extension module imports, and the rest were easy to fix. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ChrisGranade: glad I could help. Good luck with the rest of your project, I will definitely keep an eye on it!